# Calling lua_pcall clear the lua_State

Tags: c++, lua

This is a simplified version of the code I'm testing:

```
int f(lua_State *L)
{
    std::cout << std::format("- Function call, stack size: {}, parameter value: {}\n", lua_gettop(L), lua_tointeger(L, 1));
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    lua_State *const L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_loadstring(L, "f1(1)");
    luaL_loadstring(L, "f2(2)");
    lua_register(L, "f1", f);
    lua_register(L, "f2", f);

    std::cout << "\nStack before call:\n";
    for (int b = 0, e = lua_gettop(L); b != e; ++b)
        std::cout << '\t' << lua_typename(L, lua_type(L, b + 1)) << '\n';

    for (int i = 0; lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0) == 0; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "\nStack on iteration " << i << '\n';
        for (int b = 0, e = lua_gettop(L); b != e; ++b)
            std::cout << '\t' << lua_typename(L, lua_type(L, b + 1)) << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "Before exit: " << lua_tostring(L, -1);

    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting `lua_pcall` to call `f` twice each iteration of the loop, but this isn't how is it behaving, I'll paste the program output right below:

```
Stack before call:
        function
        function
- Function call, stack size: 1, parameter value: 2

Stack on iteration 0
        function
- Function call, stack size: 1, parameter value: 1

Stack on iteration 1
Before exit: attempt to call a nil value
```

I have two functions on the stack before the first call (they might be `f1` and `f2`).

1. On the first call only `f2` is called. `f1` remains on the stack.
2. On the second call  only `f1` is called. The stack is empty.
3. On the third call, `lua_pcall` fails and ends the loop.

Looks like on each call one function is popped from the stack, so obviously I'm not understanding how the Lua library works. This is what I (wrongly) thought:

- Consecutive calls to `luaL_loadstring` over the same `lua_State` pointer, adds code to the lua state, as if we were concatenating scripts.
- Each call to `lua_pcall` over the same `lua_State` pointer, the state remains unchanged as if it was interpreting the loaded script.

What should I do in order to just execute (keep the state unchanged) the code I've added to the state with `luaL_loadstring`?

Answer (score 1):

> Looks like on each call one function is popped from the stack

This is right, and your code is basically fine, the problem is after `f1(1)` is executed `lua_gettop(L)` becomes 0, so the next call to the `lua_pcall` function, you actually call an incorrect address. You may check the top first:

```
for (int i = 0; lua_gettop(L) > 0 && lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0) == 0; ++i)
```

There is a [`api_checknelems`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lapi.c.html#lua_pcallk) line in the `lua_pcall` function, but by default it does nothing, you need to define `LUAI_ASSERT` while building the lua library.

For the same reason, you should not try to obtain a string anymore

```
std::cout << "Before exit: "; // << lua_tostring(L, -1);
```

---

> What should I do in order to just execute (keep the state unchanged) the code I've added to the state with luaL_loadstring?

You can use `lua_pushvalue` to duplicate a function before calling it.

```
for (int i = 0; lua_pushvalue(L, -1), lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0) == 0; ++i)
```

Comment: So, my code is not fine after all… my assumption that `lua_pcall` does not modify the LUA state is not correct.